# Using Vite.js HMR with SCSS in a WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, vite

I'm trying to use Vite.js in a WordPress theme to process my asset files.

I've created a vite.config.js file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
   root: './resources',
   build: {
      rollupOptions: {
         input: ['./resources/test.scss'],
      },
   },
   server: {
      port: 1337,
   },
});
```

And I'm loading the Vite.js client plus the asset from the server:

```
<script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:1337/@vite/client"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:1337/test.css?ver=6.0.1">
```

But this results in a 404 error for the test.css file. When using a css/js file instead of scss, everything including HMR works fine. I'm also not getting any warning about sass needing to be installed, so I assume Vite.js skips the scss file completely for some reason.

Is it a good idea to use the rollupOptions.input option for just listing resources in the first place or is there a better way? As I'm not building a JS application, there's no entry point such as an index.html, just some js/scss files I want to process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install SASS `npm add -D sass` https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-pre-processors.

The input file is a JavaScript file `input: 'main.js'`, that itself imports the SCSS files `import './resources/test.scss';`.

Generally, the backend integration guide would help you with the setup for a multipage app like WordPress https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html.